# js get input values from the form with <div> tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've js script for gets elements array:

```
var inputs = '';
var form_name=document.getElementById("my_form");

for ( var i=0; i < form_name.elements.length; i++ ) {
 var input_name = form_name.elements[i].name;
 var input_value = form_name.elements[i].value;
 inputs += input_name + '=' + input_value + '&';
}
```

from the HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="my_form">
   <input type="text" name="input_1">
   <input type="text" name="input_2">
</form>
```

But with that script I can't get elements array from the form with a `<div></div>` tags:

```
<div><form action="" method="post" id="my_form_with_divs">
    <div><input type="text" name="input_1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="input_2"></div>
</form></div>
```

The script can't get input names and values from the `my_form_with_divs`.

What to do to get elements array from a `my_form_with_divs` form ?

Comment: Works fine, provided you use the correct id - https://jsfiddle.net/xk5doc12/

Comment: Thank you, right, I didn't catch at my draft I'm looking for help are double id=my_form_with_divs and my script won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your Javascript was looking for the wrong element.

```
var form_name=document.getElementById("my_form"); //Incorrect
var form_name=document.getElementById("my_form_with_divs");
```

But you can test out the snippet below.

```js
var inputs = '';
var form_name = document.getElementById("my_form_with_divs");

for ( var i=0; i < form_name.elements.length; i++ ) {
 var input_name = form_name.elements[i].name;
 var input_value = form_name.elements[i].value;
 console.log(input_name);
 console.log(input_value);
 inputs += input_name + '=' + input_value + '&';
}

console.log(inputs);
```

```html
<div><form action="" method="post" id="my_form_with_divs">
    <div><input type="text" name="input_1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="input_2"></div>
</form></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all the inputs a class so you can select them with document.getElementsByClassName.

```html
<div><form action="" method="post" id="my_form_with_divs">
    <div><input type="text" name="input_1" class="inputs" value="testvalue1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="input_2" class="inputs" value="testvalue2"></div>
</form></div>
<script>
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
 console.log("Name: "+inputs[i].name+" Value: "+inputs[i].value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use ids or classes on the inputs, so you can access them directly, like this:

```
<div><form action="" method="post" id="my_form_with_divs">
    <div><input id="input_1" type="text" name="input_1"></div>
    <div><input class="input_2" type="text" name="input_2"></div>
</form></div>

// javascript
var input_1 = document.getElementById('#input_1').value;
var input_2 = document.getElementsByClassName("input_2");
input_2 = input_2[0]; // this may not be the exact code, but this is the idea.
```

the only bad thing about using classes in plain javascript is you will have to iterate through them to get the values, even if there is only one or use the index. Not as good, ID is easier but too many of them in a page can kill performance. With a few ids though, you should be fine.

Comment: _"The issue is [...]"_ - no, it's not ... [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)  returns an HTMLFormControlsCollection, and that includes only actual form controls. Nesting level does not play a role in this.

Comment: It might be too long since I mucked about in form fields in vanilla. Thanks for the correction. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the FormData object and let it figure out all the elements in the form.  You just have to give it the form element.

```js
var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById('my_form_with_divs') );
var text = '';

formData.forEach(function(value, key){
   if ( text ) text += '&';
   text += key +'='+ value;
});

console.log( text );
```

```html
<div><form action="" method="post" id="my_form_with_divs">
    <div><input type="text" name="input_1" value="x"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="input_2" value="y"></div>
    <div>
        <select name="gender">
          <option>Male</option>
          <option selected>Other</option>
          <option>Male</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form></div>
```